# SQLite file is encrypted or is not a database (code 26)

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

First, sorry for my english, I'm so bad.

Here warning log:

```
10-21 16:46:19.108    4240-4273/com.costular.guaguaslapalma E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Process: com.costular.guaguaslapalma, PID: 4240
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: file is encrypted or is not a database (code 26): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM routes
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
        at com.costular.guaguaslapalma.util.Provider.query(Provider.java:76)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:857)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:200)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:461)
        at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:65)
        at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:43)
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
        at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:57)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Here my Provider:

```
> /**  * Created by Costular on 21/10/2014.  */ public class Provider
> extends ContentProvider{
> 
>     public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.costular.guaguaslapalma";
> 
>     private static final String URI_ROUTES = "content://"+AUTHORITY+"/routes";
>     private static final String URI_STOPS = "content://"+AUTHORITY+"/stops";
>     private static final String URI_SCHEDULE = "content://"+AUTHORITY+"/schedule";
> 
>     public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_ROUTES = Uri.parse(URI_ROUTES);
>     public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_STOPS = Uri.parse(URI_STOPS);
>     public static final Uri CONTENT_URI_SCHEDULE = Uri.parse(URI_SCHEDULE);
> 
>     //Some data
>     private Database database;
>     public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db";
>     public static final String TABLE_ROUTES = "routes";
>     public static final String TABLE_STOPS = "stops";
>     public static final String TABLE_SCHEDULE = "timetables";
> 
>     //URI MATCHER
>     public static UriMatcher uriMatcher;
>     // ---------MATCHERS---------------
>     // RUTAS
>     private static final int URI_MATCHER_ROUTES = 1;
>     private static final int URI_MATCHER_ROUTES_ID = 2;
>     // PARADAS
>     private static final int URI_MATCHER_STOPS = 10;
>     private static final int URI_MATCHER_STOPS_ID = 11;
>     // HOIRARIOS
>     private static final int URI_MATCHER_SCHEDULES = 20;
>     private static final int URI_MATCHER_SCHEDULES_ID = 21;
> 
>     static {
>         uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
>         uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_ROUTES, URI_MATCHER_ROUTES);
>         uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_ROUTES + "/#", URI_MATCHER_ROUTES_ID);
> 
>         uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_STOPS, URI_MATCHER_STOPS);
>         uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_STOPS + "/#", URI_MATCHER_STOPS_ID);
> 
>         uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_SCHEDULE, URI_MATCHER_SCHEDULES);
>         uriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_SCHEDULE + "/#", URI_MATCHER_SCHEDULES_ID);
>     }
> 
>     @Override
>     public boolean onCreate() {
>         database = Database.getInstance(getContext());
>         return true;
>     }
> 
>     @Override
>     public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
> 
>         String where = selection;
>         SQLiteDatabase db = database.getDatabase();
> 
> 
>         Cursor c = null;
>         if(uriMatcher.match(uri) == URI_MATCHER_ROUTES) {
> 
>             c = db.query(TABLE_ROUTES, projection, where, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
> 
>         } else if(uriMatcher.match(uri) == URI_MATCHER_ROUTES_ID) {
> 
>             where = "id = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
>             c = db.query(TABLE_ROUTES, projection, where, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
> 
>         } else if(uriMatcher.match(uri) == URI_MATCHER_STOPS) {
> 
>             c = db.query(TABLE_STOPS, projection, where, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
> 
>         } else if(uriMatcher.match(uri) == URI_MATCHER_STOPS_ID) {
> 
>             where = "id = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
>             c = db.query(TABLE_STOPS, projection, where, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
> 
>         } else if(uriMatcher.match(uri) == URI_MATCHER_SCHEDULES) {
> 
>             c = db.query(TABLE_SCHEDULE, projection, where, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
> 
>         } else { // URI MATCHER SCHEDULE ID!!!
> 
>             where = "id = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
>             c = db.query(TABLE_SCHEDULE, projection, where, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
> 
>         }
> 
>         return c;
>     }
> 
>     @Override
>     public String getType(Uri uri) {
> 
> 
>         switch(uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
> 
>             case URI_MATCHER_ROUTES:
>                 return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/com.costular.routes";
> 
>             case URI_MATCHER_ROUTES_ID:
>                 return "vnd.android.cursor.item/com.costular.routes";
> 
>             case URI_MATCHER_STOPS:
>                 return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/com.costular.stops";
> 
>             case URI_MATCHER_STOPS_ID:
>                 return "vnd.android.cursor.item/com.costular.stops";
> 
>             case URI_MATCHER_SCHEDULES:
>                 return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/com.costular.schedules";
> 
>             case URI_MATCHER_SCHEDULES_ID:
>                 return "vnd.android.cursor.item/com.costular.schedules";
>         }
> 
>         return "";
>     }
> 
>     @Override
>     public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
>         return null;
>     }
> 
>     @Override
>     public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
>         return 0;
>     }
> 
>     @Override
>     public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
>         return 0;
>     }
> 
>     public static final class RoutesCol implements BaseColumns {
> 
>         public static final String COL_ID = "id";
>         public static final String COL_START = "start";
>         public static final String COL_END = "end";
>         public static final String COL_NAME = "name";
>         public static final String COL_NUMBER = "number";
>     }
> 
>     public static final class StopsCol implements BaseColumns {
> 
>         public static final String COL_ID = "id";
>         public static final String COL_NAME = "name";
>         public static final String COL_NUMBER = "number";
>         public static final String COL_ROUTE = "route";
>     }
> 
>     public static final class ScheduleCol implements BaseColumns {
> 
>         public static final String COL_ID = "id";
>         public static final String COL_STOP = "stop";
>         public static final String COL_TIME = "time";
>         public static final String COL_RUN_WEEKEND = "run_weekend";
>         public static final String DISABLED_ACCESS = "disabled_access";
>     } }
```

Here my SQLite:

```
/**
 * Created by Costular on 17/10/2014.
 */
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        //The Android's default system path of your application database.
        private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.costular.guaguaslapalma/databases/";

        private static String DB_NAME = "databasepene";

        private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

        private final Context myContext;

        /**
         * Constructor
         * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
         * @param context
         */
        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

            super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
            this.myContext = context;
        }

        public SQLiteDatabase getDatabase() {
            return myDataBase;
        }

        /**
         * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
         * */
        public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

            if(dbExist){
                //do nothing - database already exist
            }else{

                //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
                //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
                this.getReadableDatabase();

                try {

                    copyDataBase();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    throw new Error("Error copying database");

                }
            }

        }

        /**
         * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
         * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
         */
        private boolean checkDataBase(){

            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

            try{
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

            }catch(SQLiteException e){

                //database does't exist yet.

            }

            if(checkDB != null){

                checkDB.close();

            }

            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }

        /**
         * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
         * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
         * This is done by transfering bytestream.
         * */
        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

            //Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

            //Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            //Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

        }

        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

            //Open the database
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)
                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }

        // Add your public helper methods to access and get content from the database.
        // You could return cursors by doing "return myDataBase.query(....)" so it'd be easy
        // to you to create adapters for your views.

    }
```

Comment: You should not hard code your DB_PATH, but rather determine it from getFilesDir() or similar called on the Context you are already passing to the constructor.  It's not clear why you are specifying an explicit path in some cases but using a default (specifying only filename) in others - likely that could be contributing to your problem.

Comment: have you found the answer to your problem?